# regex expression for single quotes in sql insert

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have requirement to regex replace string for 
'this is Raj's turn' to  'this is Raj''s turn'

I got the regex ('\w+\s\w+\s\w+\'[^']\w*') but i am unable to replace the single quote with 2 quotes.

This is for the custom tool which replaces the whole string to the insert hive SQL. So i want to replace the single quote with double, that it inserts the whole string in the hive tabl.e
TIA.

regards,
SK

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/Plq0ZO/1. However, this approach does not let you generalize more. You may probably use a known "trick" with `\b'\b` and replace with `''`. See https://regex101.com/r/Plq0ZO/2.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `replace`

```
String one = "this is Raj's turn";
String two = "this is Raj''s turn";

one = one.replace("'", "''");
System.out.println(one);
System.out.println(one.equals(two));
```

Even using `replaceAll` which accepts regex, the above works

```
one.replaceAll("'", "''");
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention i am using a user app tool, where java regex is used.  I need the regex expression to replace it. Thanks.

Comment: @sktemkar Why is find: `'` and replace: `''` not a valid option, even using a regex tool with Java flavor syntax?

Comment: @sktemkar your question is really so ambiguous and you made it much more confusing with above comment. Give more information about your problem please.